# Opera keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, opera

I am curious how the Opera browser implements its keyboard navigation, where you can do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + (<kbd>↑</kbd> , <kbd>↓</kbd> , <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>) and you travel along a row or a column.

How would you implement this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a starting-point:

```
function getCentrePosition(el) {
    var x= el.offsetWidth/2, y= el.offsetHeight/2;
    while (el!==null && el.nodeType==1) {
        x+= el.offsetLeft;
        y+= el.offsetTop;
        el= el.offsetParent;
    }
    return [x, y];
}

function arrowKeyHandler(event) {
    if (event===undefined) event= window.event;
    if (!event.shiftKey) return true;

    // Detect which arrow key is pressed. Make a matrix to rotate each
    // case onto the default case for left-pressed.
    //
    var m;
    if (event.keyCode===37) m= [[1,0], [0,1]]; // left
    else if (event.keyCode===38) m= [[0,1], [-1,0]]; // up
    else if (event.keyCode===39) m= [[-1,0], [0,-1]]; // right
    else if (event.keyCode===40) m= [[0,-1], [1,0]]; // down
    else return true;

    // Find link with shortest distance in left and vertical directions.
    // Disregard any links not left of the current link.
    //
    var pos= getCentrePosition(this);
    var bestlink= null, bestdist= null;
    for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;) {
        var otherpos= getCentrePosition(document.links[i]);
        var dx= (otherpos[0]-pos[0])*m[0][0] + (otherpos[1]-pos[1])*m[0][1];
        var dy= (otherpos[0]-pos[0])*m[1][0] + (otherpos[1]-pos[1])*m[1][1];
        if (dx>=0) continue;
        var dist= Math.abs(dx)+Math.abs(dy)*3; // arbitrary biasing factor
        if (bestdist===null || dist<bestdist) {
            bestlink= document.links[i];
            bestdist= dist;
        }
    }

    // Focus closest link in that direction, if any
    //
    if (bestlink!==null)
        bestlink.focus();
    return false;
}

// Add to each link on-page, except on Opera which already does it
//
if (!window.opera)
    for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;)
        document.links[i].onkeydown= arrowKeyHandler;
```

This is a simple hack that guesses the ‘best’ link in one direction by looking at the centre point of the each link compared with the current one (normalised for direction with a rotation matrix). You could probably improve this by looking at the right-edges of links when moving left, the left-edges when moving right, and so on. And probably it should be compiling a list of all focusable elements on the pages (including form fields and elements with tabindex) instead of just links.

Comment: portoalet, you should get better at accepting answers. The above is a pretty impressive effort at helping you..

Answer (score 0):

You could also call functions like document.moveFocusUp() and document.moveFocusDown() .. but that would be cheating a bit, I guess, and it would only work in Opera ;)

(Those methods hook into the built-in logic for "spatial navigation", i.e. moving focus to the link or button Opera considers the best match in a given direction)

Answer (score 0):

This can quickly and easily be done in CSS. Have a read here:

https://dev.opera.com/tv/tweaking-spatial-navigation-for-tv-browsing/

```
<a id="1" href="#" style="nav-up: #3; nav-right: #2;">Link 1</a>
<a id="2" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a id="3" href="#">Link 3</a>
```

In this example, if the focus was on `Link 1` and the user held `Shift` and pressed `Right`, the focus would jump to `Link 2`. If the user held `Shift` and pressed `Up`, the focus would jump to `Link 3`, no matter where the links were positioned on the page.